# How to group SQL results by column with help of Hash and Array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash

I have the following query:

```
select c.name,co.code from countries c
INNER JOIN continents co
on c.continent_code = co.code
INNER JOIN event_locations el
on el.location_id = c.id
```

Ruby Code:

```
 @records = Country.joins('
      INNER JOIN continents co
      on countries.continent_code = co.code
      INNER JOIN event_locations el
      on el.location_id = countries.id
  ').select('countries.name,co.code').order('co.code').all
```

Which produce results like:

```
Pakistan    AS
Uganda  AF
United States   NA
Mexico  NA
```

Now at Rails end I have to display it like:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>AS</td><td>Pakistan</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>NA</td><td>United States, Mexico</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to use same query and thinking of using Hash and push into Array. In PHP I can create an associate Array and could push values like:

```
$myArray[$continent_name][]= $country_name
```

Which can group values by Key. How can I make it possible in Rails/Ruby?

Comment: "produce results like:" like what? Is it hash, or string, or collection of objects? How do you call this query in your app?

Comment: @RustamA.Gasanov I am fetching records from Db and Have to display in HTML as I mentioned above. I want to group countries by Continents by using Rails Hash. How do I do it?

Comment: So first of all, you should turn this query to AR calls and perform it in application(how? we don't know, you didn't show any code), and only after that think about how to group results. Btw you can group them with sql too.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of the PHP you wrote is:

```
hash_with_default_array = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }
@records.reduce(hash_with_default_array) do |result, record|
  result[record.code] << record.name
  result
end
```

However, the exact way you will deliver your data from the database to the web will depend on which ORM (if any) you're using (ActiveRecord, Sequel, DataMapper, plain SQL...), and which HTML templating solution (if any) you're using (ERb, Slim, Haml, string concatenation...)

Answer (score 0):

`group_by` is your friend.

```
### Mock of ActiveRecord
Country = Struct.new(:name, :continent)
records = [
  Country.new("Pakistan", "AS"),
  Country.new("Uganda", "AF"),
  Country.new("United States", "NA"),
  Country.new("Mexico", "NA")
]

### The interesting bit
records.group_by(&:continent).each do |continent, countries|
  puts "#{continent}: #{countries.map(&:name).join(", ")}"
end
```